# stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra, capybara

I have Sinatra application and need to test my application.

**features/support/env.rb:**

```
require_relative "../../application"

require "capybara"
require "capybara/cucumber"
require "rspec"

World do
  Capybara.app = Application

  include Capybara::DSL
  include RSpec::Matchers
end
```

**features/one.feature:**

```
Feature: Test homepage
  In order to make sure people can open my site
  I want to check it opened

  Scenario: Opening first page
    Given I have opened homepage    
    Then I should see site header
```

Test it:

```
cucumber features\one.feature
```

Result:

```
Feature: Test homepage
  In order to make sure people can open my site
  I want to check it opened

  Scenario: Opening first page    # features\one.feature:5
    Given I have opened homepage  # features\one.feature:6
    Then I should see site header # features\one.feature:7

1 scenario (1 undefined)
2 steps (2 undefined)
0m0.006s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I have opened homepage$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then /^I should see site header$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Well, I have created **features/step_definitions/agenda_steps.rb:**

```
Given /^I have opened homepage$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then /^I should see site header$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Test it:

```
cucumber features\one.feature
```

Result:

```
Feature: Test homepage
  In order to make sure people can open my site
  I want to check it opened

  Scenario: Opening first page    # features\one.feature:5
    Given I have opened homepage  # features/step_definitions/agenda_steps.rb:1
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:19: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Why and how can I fix it?

**Updated:**  the problem dissapeared if I rewrite my env.rb like this:

```
require_relative "../../application"

require "capybara"
require "capybara/cucumber"
require "rspec"


Capybara.app = Application
#World do
#  Capybara.app = Application
# 
#  include Capybara::DSL
#  include RSpec::Matchers
#end
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile.lock also or more so what versions of cucumber, capybara and rspec you are using

Comment: I have posted my Gemfile.lock here: http://pastebin.com/8Ni5MSdj

Comment: @Jacob, Rspec is for assertions while Capybara just talks to the web Driver. With that being said, you definitely need both Rspec & Capybara (& probably Selenium too)

Answer (score 1):

i was getting the same look alike error..as

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:73..
```

i added `require 'cucumber/rails'` on **first line of env.rb**...which get loaded first.

Now no more im facing that error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only `Capybara.app = Application` **should not** be declared inside `World` as show in your example.

So here is mine working *env.rb*:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'rvs.rb')

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'rspec'
require 'r18n-core'

Capybara.app = RVS

class RVSWorld
  include R18n::Helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  include RSpec::Expectations
  include RSpec::Matchers
end

World do
  RVSWorld.new
end
```

As you can see RVSWorld class has only statements which includes necessary modules.